# C++ files stopped compiling - keep getting error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I've had no problems compiling in the past, and code that I wrote previously is compiling fine, but it is now giving this error when I try to compile a very simple C++ file using Visual Studio Code on my M1 Mac:

Code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The terminal commands I've tried (all give same error):

```
g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've tried to delete and re-create the file with different names, restarting VSC, using different output file names and nothing changes this.

Comment: It looks like your `gcc`'s linker is installed for `x86_64` architecture, but the compiler does something different because M1 is not `x86_64`. I'd suspect some virtualization mismatch.

Comment: I've not installed anything prior to this happening - I haven't used the laptop in a couple of weeks.
Doing `g++ --version` returns (amongst other things)
`Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
`
I'm very new to this and very confused why it's randomly started happening. All I did before the issue was create a new file in the directory using the echo command but this is happening with files created via the GUI of VSC too

Comment: What you should be seeing as target is [arm64-apple-darwin20.1.0](https://build2.org/blog/apple-m1-compilation.xhtml)

Comment: I get that when I run clang / g++ --version in the terminal, but not when I do it in VSC

Comment: for crying out loud, I hadn't turned on auto-save on and wasn't saving it myself so it couldn't find the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was occurring as I hadn't saved the file prior to compiling and therefore the compiler couldn't find it.

Comment: Welcome to the club! There are many reasons to use an IDE instead of a text editor and the command line and that is one of them...

Comment: I was using VSC for this so have even fewer excuses!

Comment: An IDE should warn you when that happens. Or save everything automatically when you start to build. Changing files on disk is no problem anymore since the invention of version control systems...